# How to pass state to component?

Tags: react-router, redux

I am new to redux and react-router. In the `Product` component, I can access the productId, but how can I access the store? Or how can I pass the product to the component?

Reducer

```
const reducer = combineReducers({
  products: (state = []) => state,
  routing: routerReducer
});

const store = createStore(
  reducer, {
    products: [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Product A',
      price: 1000
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Product B',
      price: 2000
    }]
  }
);
```

Components

```
const Product = ({params}) => (
  <div>
    Id: {params.productId}
  </div>
  );

class Products extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Products</h1>
        <ul>
          {this.props.children || 
            this.props.products.map(product => (
              <li key={product.id}>
                <Link to={`/products/${product.id}`} >{product.name}</Link>
              </li>))}
        </ul>
      </div>
      );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    products: state.products
  }
};

const ProductsContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps
)(Products)
```

Routes:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    { /* Tell the Router to use our enhanced history */ }
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
        <Route path="products" component={ProductsContainer}>
          <Route path=":productId" component={Product}/>
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Product is a container. Because you put it in the route.
So you should use the connect and mapStateToProps function to transmit the store, just like what you do in Products container.

Comment: Thanks. Because originally I thought a container (i.e. ProductsContainer) cannot be a parent of another container.